# Want to reverse an array of numbers C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have some code written but I'm not sure why the reversed array is not giving me the exact values I need. I created a second array the same size as the first and used nested for loops to fill the second with the contents of the first in reverse.
See below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Ask for how big the array is
    int n;
    cout << "how big is the array?" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    // create array
    int a[n];
    // create second array
    int b[n];
    // ask for contents of the 1st array
    cout << "what's in the array?" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    // reverse the array
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            b[k] = a[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    // print out the new array
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        cout << b[k] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use `std::reverse` and call it good. I'd also use standard containers; VLAs (variable length arrays like `int a[n]` and `int b[n]` are *not* standard, fyi). Regardless, you said, "the reversed array is not giving me the exact values I need." That implies you have a specific expectation of a specific output, given a specific input, but instead are getting something different. *All* of that should be included in your post: the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Suggestion: One array and one loop. Set a pointer, begin, to the first element in the array and a pointer, end, to the last element. Then while the end pointer is greater than the begin pointer, swap the values of the pointed-at elements and move both pointers one spot toward the middle (begin forward and end back) of the array. This will march to the middle of the array and you do half of the work.

Comment: Look at the `break` statement. It makes only the first element of `b` assigned,  others uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need 2 bucles for fill the second array
try with:

```
//reverse the array
s = 0;
for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    b[n]=a[s];
    s++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace {
template <typename IStream>
[[nodiscard]] int readOneIntFrom(IStream& istream) {
    int x;
    istream >> x;
    return x;
}
}

int main()
{
    // Ask for how big the array is
    std::cout << "how big is the array?" << std::endl;
    auto n = readOneIntFrom(std::cin);
    // create array
    std::vector<int> a;

    // ask for contents of the 1st array
    std::cout << "what's in the array?" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a.emplace_back(readOneIntFrom(std::cin)); // Make a new entry at the end of a.
    }
    // Construct b from a backward. (Or do auto b = a; std::reverse(b.begin(), b.end());
    auto b = std::vector<int>(a.rbegin(), a.rend());

    // print out the new array
    for (const auto& bi : b)
    {
        std::cout << bi << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```